# Finding repetitions of multiple lines in a text file

Tags: algorithm, text

I have a file with multiple lines where a block of adjacent lines may be repeated.

For example, in the following file, lines 1..8 are the same as lines 9..17:

```
ERROR2
ERROR3
ERROR4
CHANGE
RESET1
RESET2
RESET3
ERROR1
ERROR2
ERROR3
ERROR4
CHANGE
RESET1
RESET2
RESET3
ERROR1
SPAM
ERROR2
ERROR3
ERROR4
CHANGE
RESET1
RESET2
RESET3
ERROR1
ERROR2
ERROR3
```

I would like the tool to find regions of adjacent repeated lines and give me some indication of the repeat and how many times it is repeated e.g., if the first column of the output below is a repeat count and the lines repeated are up to the next repeat count, then the answer could be:

```
2   ERROR2
    ERROR3
    ERROR4
    CHANGE
    RESET1
    RESET2
    RESET3
    ERROR1
1   SPAM
    ERROR2
    ERROR3
    ERROR4
    CHANGE
    RESET1
    RESET2
    RESET3
    ERROR1
    ERROR2
    ERROR3
```

How do I do this sort of thing? Is there a pre-written utility? Failing that, a program or algorithm?

Thanks.

Comment: There's a brute way of doing this. Keep adding the words to a dictionary and the frequency as their value.

Comment: The following Python regexp seems to match what I am after and could be expanded into a program:

    embedded_rawstr = r"""(?ms)(?P<repeat>(?P<lines>^.*?$)(?:\n(?P=lines))+)"""

Comment: This is a basic form of data compression. You want to do more or less the same gzip does (simplified of course). Read up om theory and implementation of data compressors like LZ77.

Comment: @n.m. It is similar, but I need to be left with something readable that I can reason about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote something based on the multi-line capturing regexp of my comment above:

```
r"""(?ms)(?P<repeat>(?P<lines>^.*?$)(?:\n(?P=lines))+)"""
```

**EDIT**

I finally blogged about my solution [here](http://paddy3118.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/find-repeated-blocks-of-lines-in-text.html).

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is to go through the file and build a dictionary of "biwords". That is, `ERROR2-ERROR3` is a biword, as is `ERROR3-ERROR4`. For each entry in the dictionary, store the locations where they exist.

Once that dictionary is constructed, go through and discard every biword that occurs only once in the file. By definition it can't be repeated.

From the remaining dictionary, you can sort the entries and create a "triword" dictionary using a very similar process. You can repeat that up to an n-word dictionary until there are no more repeated sequences of that length.

Obviously each time through the list you'll want to examine the n-words that don't become (n+1)-words. So when you find repeated sequences of four words that aren't part of a 5-word sequence, you'll want to examine them.

That's not a terribly efficient algorithm, but it has the advantage of simplicity. And although it has theoretically horrible worst case behavior, it could work very well in your situation. The real world running time will depend on how large the file is, how many repeated sequences you have, and how long they are. It's quite possible that after the first pass (biwords), your data size shrinks such that the inefficient algorithm works just fine.